# Passing a value to a popup box (popup builder)

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

What I am trying to accomplish is passing a value to a popup builder popup.  Inside this popup is a shortcode with a placeholder.  This value is to update this placeholder.  The following code shows me the object data but I don't know how to update the shortcode with this variable.  Can you please help?
`var popupObj2 = SGPBPopup.createPopupObjById(2456); console.log('Popup value:', popupObj2);`

I have tried something to this effect but it's just coming back with a generic error message.

```
var popupObj2 = SGPBPopup.createPopupObjById(2456);
popupObj2 = popupObj2 .replace(/\[wpdatatable id=4 var1="([^"]*)"\]/g, '[wpdatatable id=4 var1="' + myVar + '"]');

        // Display the updated popup content
        jQuery('.popup-content').html(popupObj2);
```